# Mixed Integer Linear Programming with pyomo or PuLP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I am new to optimization programming using python and I have a problem with defining a variable in both pyomo and PuLP for a MILP problem. I am using gene expression data and I am confused about how to define a variable as a MXN matrix. I am trying to use either pyomo or PuLP. I know how to use MATLAB and define it so I am putting it make it more helpful to anyone to understand.

**y = optimvar('y',M,N,'Type','integer','LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',1)**

Also If you think there are better python package please give me your suggestion.

Thank you very much in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I'd pick `pyomo`.  I think it is more expressive and easier to read/work with.  You'll need to install a solver separately.  If that is daunting, `pulp` comes with `CBC` built in.

This should get you started.  There are a decent number of examples in the pyomo documentation to get you started.

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

m = pe.ConcreteModel('example')

m.M = pe.Set(initialize=[1, 2, 3], name='the M set')
m.N = pe.Set(initialize=['A', 'B', 'C'], name='the N set')

m.X = pe.Var(m.M, m.N, domain=pe.NonNegativeReals)

m.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
3 Set Declarations
    M : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}
    N : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'A', 'B', 'C'}
    X_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    M*N :    9 : {(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'C'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'A'), (3, 'B'), (3, 'C')}

1 Var Declarations
    X : Size=9, Index=X_index
        Key      : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        (1, 'A') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 'B') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 'C') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (2, 'A') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (2, 'B') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (2, 'C') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (3, 'A') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (3, 'B') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (3, 'C') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

4 Declarations: M N X_index X
[Finished in 1.5s]
```

================
Edit:  Making crossed sets

Some variation of below should work fine.  You can either make a full x-set by initializing to the cross of two sets, or if your model is sparse, and it makes sense, I'd encourage you to use the `within` keyword to control the domain and only populated necessary pairs with `initialize` as shown.

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

m = pe.ConcreteModel('example')

m.M = pe.Set(initialize=[1, 2, 3], name='the M set')
m.N = pe.Set(initialize=['A', 'B', 'C'], name='the N set')
m.cross = pe.Set(within=m.M*m.N, initialize = [(1,'A'), (3,'B')])
```

Comment: Hello @AirSquid, Thank you very much for your answer, but I just like to clarification, What i anted to mean was every set I have is two dimensional. Therefore, I am little confused how to do it using pyomo

Comment: Updated showing a x-set